# Make fullscreen and get height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullscreen

I'm trying to make use of the fullscreen API through this plugin:
https://github.com/private-face/jquery.fullscreen

I bind to the "fscreenchange" event and log the element height as well as $(window).height() - BOTH of which are NOT the actual window height. I'm getting 1315 instead of 1440, my window's actual height.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: Hmm -- $(window).height() = 1315, but screen.height = 1440. Why the difference?

Comment: A fiddle to demonstrate your issue?